# Why does my macbook pro power off the internal SSD drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I moved the HDD to optical drive bay, and in it's place put in a 128 GB SSD Adata SP600 128 GB drive.

I have been facing a peculiar problem. Whenever I try to install OSX on the drive either via USB drive installer or via cloning OSX partition of the original HDD, the drive gets powered off, midway through the operation.

Disc utility cannot see the drive then. On some occasions system information shows it under SATA devices connected to Intel 7 series chipset. On others it doesn't.

Then there are occasions where the Disk Utility can see the drive (after a system restart), but cannot mount the partition. If I erase and re-format the drive, the partition gets mounted.

I have already:
1. Gotten Amazon to replace the drive - only for the problem to persist.
2. Reset PRAM
3. Reset SMC
4. Enabled TRIM (dunno if that would change anything, but I thought I'll mention it anyway).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What model MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with placing a hard drive in the optical bay of 2011 and later model MacBook Pros.  It is caused by electromagnetic interference (EMI) from an unshielded WiFi/Bluetooth ribbon cable that passes directly over the optical bay between the radio (right next to the optical drive) and a connector on the motherboard (right next to the optical bay SATA connector).

Normally, this interference doesn't matter.  The EMI gets absorbed by the optical drive's metal case and the metal outer case of the MacBook Pro.  Also, the optical drive is a SATA-2 device even though the connector is SATA-3.  The lower speed requirements of the optical drive mean that it can handle a little interference with no problems.  This is the way Apple designed it - tight and compact.

[image: Factory-equipped optical drive]

When it comes to an optical bay HDD adapter, however, a portion of the logic board for the caddy (which is also unshielded) is directly underneath the WiFi/Bluetooth ribbon.

[image: HDD optical bay adapter]

In this scenario, the hard drive receives too much interference from the WiFi radios.  If you looked at the SMART data for the drive, you would see a very high volume of dropped/corrupt packets, hundreds of error corrections per second, and a bus reset every now and then.

It's the bus reset that is killing you.  When the interference becomes too high, the entire SATA bus resets, and your hard drives drop off the map.

Your only real option here is to see if you can place the optibay's hard drive into SATA-2 operation.  Some drives have a jumper for this.  The drive will be slower in this mode, but the reduced speed means a higher tolerance for errors.

If you're really brave, you could sheild the cables yourself with some foil and electrical tape, but honestly, it would look horrid, and if you do it wrong you'd fry something.  But there are web forums where people have done this.

---

Bottom line... placing a hard drive into the optical bay of a MacBook Pro is unsupported.  It is known to work only with slower SATA-2 drives, or in 2010 and older MacBook Pros (which only had a SATA-2 connector anyway).